# Django exception when trying to show a DateTimeField on an admin form

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have a model that defines a datetimefield:

```
dateAdded = models.DateTimeField("Date Added", auto_now_add=True)
```

In my ModelAdmin subclass I'm trying to show the field in the following field set:

```
fieldsets = (
    (None, {
        'fields': (
            ("modelId", "altModelIds", "modelName", "dateAdded"),
            ("manufacturer", "protocol", "category"),
            ("versionAdded", "proOnly", "published", "discontinued"),
            "notes"
        )
    }),
```

but I get the following error:

```
FieldError: Unknown field(s) (dateAdded) specified for Device
```

Interestingly, though, when I add it to a list_display:

```
list_display = ("modelName", "published", "modelId", "altModelIds", "manufacturer", "protocol", "category", "dateAdded")
```

It works fine. I'm sure I'm just doing something stupid (I've been away from Django for about 8 months) but I can't figure it out. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: plesse post the complete models.py and admin.py

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because datetimefield model field types that are marked auto_now_add are also implicitly given editable=False then they aren't shown on change forms. If you specify the field in a field set in a ModelAdmin class, it's apparently not considered to be in the model because it's read-only. Silly error message actually since it is in the model but that's the way it is.

Now to figure out how to show the field read-only on a change form for the model (but that's a different problem).